# How to provide configuration in a functional way

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, next.js

I'm currently digging into functional programming and I am trying to create a package that should be configurable. I want this configuration to be done only once. Currently I saved some of them in environment variables which is not necessary in that case and considered bad practice. Also I would like to keep my functions pure, but I don't know how I would be able to setup my methods providing this configuration without accessing global state.

Imagine I had a file like that:

```
import { readFile } from 'foo';
import { join } from 'path';

const contentPath = process.env.CONTENT_PATH || './some/path';

export const getSomething = (file) => {
 return readFile(join(contentPath, 'documents', file))
}

export const getSomethingElse = (file) => {
 return readFile(join(contentPath, 'data', file))
}
```

Then I had a setup script like this (I am creating this for nextjs):

```
const withSvgr = require('next-svgr');
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@baretheme/fs', '@baretheme/core']);

module.exports = (pluginOptions = {}) => (nextConfig = {}) => {
  const contentPath = pluginOptions.contentPath || 'content';
  return withTM(withSvgr({
    ...nextConfig,
    env: {
      ...nextConfig.env,
      CONTENT_PATH: contentPath,
    },
    webpack(config, options) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      config.node = {
        ...config.node,
        fs: 'empty',
      };

      if (typeof nextConfig.webpack === 'function') {
        return nextConfig.webpack(config, options);
      }

      return config;
    },
  }));
};
```

So I could setup my package that way:

```
const setupMyPackage = require('my-package');

const myPackage = setupMyPackage({ ... });

module.exports = myPackage({ ... })
```

I really like the way currying is used here to first get the plugin configuration and then pass the nextConfig, however where should I save the `pluginOptions` in my package?

The solution I currently have in mind is creating a setup script like this:

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { getSomething, getSomethingElse } from './lib';

export function setup(options) {
  const defaults = {
    documentsPath: join(options.contentPath, 'documents'),
    dataPath: join(options.contentPath 'data'),
  };

  const config = {
    ...defaults,
    ...options,
  };

  return {
    getSomething: getSomething(config), // should be curried?
    getSomethingElse: getSomethingElse(config)
  };
}
```

It also makes use of currying by first providing the config to my methods. However to use this one would probably first have to create a file that imports my setup, call it and pass the config and export again. Then he would have to import that file instead of my package. I would prefer if you could just call the setup first and then import my functions anywhere. Is this even possible without saving that config globally? Is it a bad practice or am I complicating things?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution which should be a design decision at the very beggining of your project is using `Reader` monad.

One may use it to chain functions which delay their execution until you give and *environment* so they all get them as their last argument.

Here's a very simplified example using `Ramda` to avoid boilerplate:

```js
const { map, pipeK } = R
const I = x => x
const C = f => x => y => f (y) (x)

const Reader = C (map) (I)

const f = Reader (x => ({ y }) => x + y)
const g = Reader (x => ({ y }) => x + y + 2)
const h = Reader (x => ({ y }) => x + y + 2)

const compute = pipeK (f, g, h)

const env = { y: 1 }
const output = compute (1) (env)

console.log (output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Now's time to investigate about *readers* to learn more!